# going to an endpoont directly says page not found - netlify

Tags: angular, hosting, netlify

I have created a todo app using angular 16 and hosted it on netlify.
The url for the app is `https://todo-ang.netlify.app/`.
When I click add item it goes to endpoint /add and eveerything works fine.
Now if I directly type `https://todo-ang.netlify.app/add` it says page not found.

I am not sure how to fix this. Any help and some insights on how this works would be really appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, the link 'https://todo-ang.netlify.app/home' also throws 'Page Not Found' when opened directly.

Comment: Yes that is the issue. You have to go to https://todo-ang.netlify.app first and it will redirect to /home. But if you goto any endpoint it wont show

Answer (score 1):

I added following build command which redirects every endpoint hit to /index.html and now it is working.

> `npm run build && cd dist/angtut && touch _redirects && echo "/*    /index.html   200" > _redirects`

Here it adds _redirects file which conveys netlify to process any endpoint through index.html and from there angular router takes care of routing to respective endpoint.

I am curious to know if there exist any simpler way to add the _redirects file to dist folder after building on netlify.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because you use GET instead POST request. As I can see in Postman, actually GET returns 404 http status, but POST works properly.